# Transfer Time Machine backups to new external drive Big Sur

Tags: backup, time-machine, big-sur, data-transfer

My existing external drive (SSD) which has my Time Machine backups is getting full, so I got a new larger HD (spinning disk), and I would like to transfer the existing backups to the new one. All the methods I've seen on the web don't work:

- Drag-n-drop the backup folders onto the new HD in Finder
- Use Disk Utility to restore the original TM disk to the new one
- Register the disk as a TM disk within Time Machine System Preference, and then attempt a drag-n-drop copy

My existing TM disk is formatted APFS (Case sensitive, encrypted), and I formatted the new drive similarly. The Finder just refuses to allow the drag-n-drop copy. Is this even possible any more in macOS 11.6 Big Sur?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try with Carbon Copy Cloner doing a clone.

Comment: Formating a HDD as APFS is *possible* but not the intended use of the APFS file system, so HFS+ is a better fit. Also, you know that TM backup drive will always fill up  at some point and only *some old* backups will be deleted, right?

Comment: @X_841 regardless of what FS supposedly works best on what type of drive, Time Machine will format your TM disk as APFS, so that is a moot point. Also my current TM disk is just too small for the amount of data that is being backed up.

Comment: @X_841 - Up to Catalina, Time Machine was on HFS+. Since Big Sur, it's on APFS. There is no workaround for that. [Conrad - I've no experience with copying the new format, sorry.]

Comment: Have you tried copying the backup folders in Finder *before* setting up the new drive as a TM disk? That is, format the new drive with APFS, copy the contents of the TM disk and then add the new drive to Time Machine, in the hope it will recognize the backups and ask whether to import them. You could also use `dd if=/dev/rdiskX of=/dev/rdiskY` (X and Y are numbers, see https://medium.com/@kepler.donald/create-exact-clone-of-macintosh-hd-with-dd-command-line-564e62161346) to clone the current Time Machine disk to the new drive, and then (hopefully) extend the container to the whole disk.

Comment: @jaume yes I tried that - Finder wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @jaume to be precise, when you try to drag Time Machine backups from the old drive to the new one, the Finder shows you a "blocked" symbol preventing you from copying the files over to the new drive